# Python:Bad Window Path Name when using deiconify

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I've been having this problem with a python program I am making where if I display a TopLevel window, in this case my Help Menu, then withdraw it then try to display it again I get the following error

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\****\Documents\GitHub\ProjectName\ProjectName\GUI.py", line 60, in     displayHelp
    self.helpMenu.display();
  File "C:\Users\****\Documents\GitHub\ProjectName\ProjectName\HelpMenu.py", line 35, in display
    self.deiconify();
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1646, in wm_deiconify
    return self.tk.call('wm', 'deiconify', self._w)
_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".60000336"
```

The error first happened when I was withdrawing from within HelpMenu.py and using deiconify to redisplay it from the GUI.py file. 
Since then I have tried multiple ways to fix the problem including calling deiconify from within HelpMenu.py and updating the copy of help menu stored in the GUI when I withdraw it.
I am running Python 3.4.2

I have already done extensive searches online and failed to find a solution to my problem. I have found other mentions of this error but they either didn't relate to my situation or their solutions did not work.

Here is the entire code for the HelpMenu.py followed by an extract from GUI.py that retains the functionality to reproduce the error but has other code removed.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
try:
    from Tkinter import *
except ImportError:
    from tkinter import *

class HelpMenu(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent, observer):
        Toplevel.__init__(self);
        self.observer = observer;#Observer is the GUI, this is here just so I can update the GUI when I withdraw this window
        self.setup();
        self.withdraw();
        self.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.quit());#Changes the close button to just hide the window

    def setup(self):
       self.columnconfigure(0,weight=1);
       w = 400;#Sets up the window position on the screen
       h = 150;
       sw = self.winfo_screenwidth();
       sh = self.winfo_screenheight();
       x=(sw-w)/2;
       y =(sh-h)/2;
       self.update();
       self.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w,h,x,y));
       self.resizable(width=0, height=0);
       self.grid();
       self.title("Help Menu");
    def quit(self):#Hides the window
       self.withdraw();
       self.observer.updateHelp(self);
    def display(self):#Re-displays the window
        self.deiconify();
```

Here is code taken from GUI.py and modified to only have the code needed to reproduce the issue.

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
#Allows compatibility with any version of Python by checking for both versions of Tkinter
try:
    from Tkinter import *
except ImportError:
    from tkinter import *
#Imports the AutoCompleteEntry
from HelpMenu import HelpMenu

class UI(Tk):
    def initialize(self):
        #Handles setting up most of the GUI
        w = 500;#Window width
        h = 500;#Window height
        sw = self.winfo_screenwidth();#Gets screen width
        sh = self.winfo_screenheight();#Gets screen height
        x=(sw-w)/2;#Calculates the x position for the left side of the window that allows it to be placed in the center of the screen
        y =(sh-h)/2;#Calculates the y position for the top of the window that allows it to be placed in the center of the screen
        self.update();#Forces and update on the window
        self.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w,h,x,y));#Sets the windows width, height and position
        self.minsize(int(w),int(h/2));#Sets the minimum size of the window
        self.configureMenu();
    def updateHelp(self, helpMenu):
        self.helpMenu=helpMenu;
    def displayHelp(self):
        self.helpMenu.display();
    def configureMenu(self):
        #Handles configuring and setting up the menus
        menu = Menu(self);#Setup the menu bar
        menu.add_command(label="Help",command=self.displayHelp);
        self.config(menu=menu);
    def __init__(self, parent):
     #Handles the initial call to create a GUI
        Tk.__init__(self,parent);#Parent constructor
        self.parent = parent;#Store the parent
        self.initialize();#Initilize the GUI
        self.helpMenu = HelpMenu(self, self);
        self.mainloop();#Start the main loop
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    main = UI(None);
```

One last note, I am slightly new to Python, so there might be other errors in my code and while I wont mind if they get pointed out, the main focus I have right now is fixing this path name error.

EDIT:Almost a month now and I have still not found a solution to the problem. Any help would be great but at this point I am probably going to have to abandon my project.

Comment: What did you do in the self.config(menu=menu)? It's hard to identify issue with only part of code.

Comment: All the code is there, the self.config(menu=menu) is from Tkinter, it sets the menu bar for the window to be the one I setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after a break I went back to look at this problem again.

Turns out that the issue was self.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.quit()) was not actually calling self.quit() and was destroying the window completely.

A quick change to self.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.quit) seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe the comma causes the problem. Try write it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

try:
    from Tkinter import *
except ImportError:
    from tkinter import *

class HelpMenu(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent, observer):
        Toplevel.__init__(self)
        self.observer = observer  # Observer is the GUI, this is here just so I can update the GUI when I withdraw this window
        self.setup()
        self.withdraw()
        self.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.quit())  # Changes the close button to just hide the window

    def setup(self):
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        w = 400  # Sets up the window position on the screen
        h = 150
        sw = self.winfo_screenwidth()
        sh = self.winfo_screenheight()
        x = (sw - w) / 2
        y = (sh - h) / 2
        self.update()
        self.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
        self.resizable(width=0, height=0)
        self.grid()
        self.title("Help Menu")
    def quit(self):  # Hides the window
        self.withdraw()
        self.observer.updateHelp(self)
    def display(self):  # Re-displays the window
        self.deiconify()


class UI(Tk):
    def initialize(self):
        # Handles setting up most of the GUI
        w = 500  # Window width
        h = 500  # Window height
        sw = self.winfo_screenwidth()  # Gets screen width
        sh = self.winfo_screenheight()  # Gets screen height
        x = (sw - w) / 2  # Calculates the x position for the left side of the window that allows it to be placed in the center of the screen
        y = (sh - h) / 2  # Calculates the y position for the top of the window that allows it to be placed in the center of the screen
        self.update()  # Forces and update on the window
        self.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))  # Sets the windows width, height and position
        self.minsize(int(w), int(h / 2))  # Sets the minimum size of the window
        self.configureMenu()
    def updateHelp(self, helpMenu):
        self.helpMenu = helpMenu
    def displayHelp(self):
        self.helpMenu.display()
    def configureMenu(self):
        # Handles configuring and setting up the menus
        menu = Menu(self)  # Setup the menu bar
        menu.add_command(label="Help", command=self.displayHelp)
        self.config(menu=menu)
    def __init__(self, parent):
        # Handles the initial call to create a GUI
        Tk.__init__(self, parent)  # Parent constructor
        self.parent = parent  # Store the parent
        self.initialize()  # Initilize the GUI
        self.helpMenu = HelpMenu(self, self)
        self.mainloop()  # Start the main loop
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = UI(None)
```

It works perfectly from myside.

Comment: Assuming you mean the semicolons then no, that did not work, its still doing the exact same thing as before.

Comment: @Alex Yes, semicolons, my mistake. Still the same TclError? What version of Python are you using?